# What are all the possible variable fields available in greetings (Email and Postal)?

Tags: civimail

When defining new email and postal greeting formats in Administer > Communications > Email Greeting Formats, I see several available variables like `{contact.first_name}`, `{contact.last_name}`, and so on.

I would be happy to see the list of **all** available variables.

More precisely, when I refer to `{contact.individual_prefix}`, I have access to the field `Label` of the corresponding table, but I want to access the field `Description` of the same table. I would like to know if this is possible, and if I have to install some extension in order to achieve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see a list of the tokens when creating a mail message (e.g. with mailings > New Mailings). You will see a drop down for the tokens in the top right of the mail body. If you select one you'll see the full token in the message body which you can then use in the greeting format.